# Transpone data in a data frame

Tags: r

I have a dataset that looks like this

```
 playlist nr1     nr2
 1        jam     sequel
 2        monster equal
```

What i would like to do now is to now is to transpone the data so I get:

```
  playlist data     
  1        jam     
  1        sequel
```

Been googling around for a solution but couldn't find it. Any thoughts on how I can accomplish this?

Comment: Are you sure of your expected output?

Comment: `library(reshape2); melt(mydf, "playlist")`?

Comment: If you really want to transpose your data, t(df) will work (in your case t(playlist) ) but the outcome isn't exactly as you described.

Comment: I'm wondering if 'playlist' is the name of your data frame or another column of your unnamed data frame and you've also missed out the index?

Answer (score 1):

If you'd like to stick to standard R packages, use reshape():

```
df <- data.frame(playlist=1:2, 
                 nr1=c('jam', 'monster'), 
                 nr2=c('sequel', 'equal'))
dfnew <- reshape(df, 
                 varying=2:3, 
                 direction='long', 
                 sep='')
dfnew[order(dfnew$playlist), c('playlist', 'nr')]
```

Comment: Good use of `reshape`, plus one.

Answer (score 0):

Data frame built with your data

```
playlist  <- data.frame(nr1=c("jam","monster"),
                        nr2=c("sequel","equal"))

t(playlist) ## transposes the data
```

This gives what you asked but not what your example said?

```
    [,1]     [,2]     
nr1 "jam"    "monster"
nr2 "sequel" "equal"
```

Answer (score 0):

We may need `melt`

```
library(reshape2)
 melt(df1, id.var='playlist')[-2]
```